# Getting no matches found error for aws logs list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn <arn-value>

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm getting no matched found error while executing the below aws cli code

`aws logs list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn <arn-value>`

The arn-value above is a CloudWatch Log Group Arn.

I was expecting an output below

`tags -> (map)

The list of tags associated with the requested resource.>

key -> (string)

value -> (string)`

I have tried looking into AWS CLI documentation.